# Concatenating a Character to Array Values in SAS

Tags: sas

I am having trouble concatenating a letter to array values in SAS. I would like to add a letter to the beginning of every number value in this array. Here is what I have that is not working:

```
array GRPAry G01-G18;

do i = 1 to 18;

if GRPAry[i] = 1 then GRPAry[i] = "G"||i;

else if GRPAry[i] = 1 then GRPAry[i] = .;

end;

split = ',';

EDGE_GRP_SUM = catx(split, of G01-G18);

drop split;

drop i;
```

it will run but will not return anything in the EDGE_GRP_SUM field.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Are your variables character or numeric? If numeric your also doing a type conversion which cannot be done in place in SAS, you need a new set of variables.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you're defining `EDGE_GRP_SUM` to a sufficient length.  `CATX` will return missing if it's trying to create too long of a string for the output variable, and that's by default 200 I think in this context.  Always define its full length in the code when using the CAT family of functions.

Second, the line:

```
if GRPAry[i] = 1 then GRPAry[i] = "G"||i;
```

Is wrong, in some fashion.  If `GRPAry` is numeric, then it's not possible to store `"G"||i` in it.  If it's character, then `GRPAry[i]=1` is incorrect (though it may work anyway).

Since GRPAry is numeric, you can do this:

```
array GRPAry G01-G18;
split=',';
do i = 1 to 18;
  if GRPAry[i] = 1 then 
      EDGE_GRP_SUM = catx(split, EDGE_GRP_SUM, vname(GRPAry[i]));
end;
drop split i;
```

Seems easier than copying over to a character array.  `VNAME` gets you the variable name.

Comment: GRPAry is numeric right now, do you have any suggestions on how i can make this work?

Comment: Make a parallel character array.

Comment: I tried this 
array GRPAry G01-G18;
array GRPAry2 $ GR01-GR18;
   do i = 1 to 18;
   if GRPAry[i] = 1 then do;
   GRPAry[i] = i;
   GRPAry2[i] = "G"|GrpAry[i];
   end;
   end;

split = ',';
EDGE_GRP_SUM = catx(split, of GR01-GR18);
drop split;
drop i;

ugh i don't know how to copy code to comment sorry. obviously that's not the way it's done b/c its not working.

Comment: @wongtak I addressed this in an update.  I wouldn't bother copying to a char array - if you're going to loop anyway, just do the construction in the loop rather than using the `of` model.